# Radio button groups

Tags: jquery

I have a radio button group (see code below)  :

```
<tr>
                <td>
                    Total Meter :
                </td>  
                <td style="width:10px;"></td>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="Yes" style="border-style:none;" /> Yes
                </td>
                <td style="width:10px;"></td>
                <td>    
                    <input type="radio" name="rdoInput" value="No" style="border-style:none;" /> No
                </td>
            </tr>
```

My question is, how do I set and get the value of these?  I have tried this syntax to set the values, but it does not work :

```
if (msg.d.Input == true) {
                         $('input[name="rdoInput"]').attr('checked', true);
                     }
                     else {
                         $('input[name="rdoInput"]').attr('checked', false);
                     }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: That table layout looks amazing... especially those empty cells that emulate padding-left. `:D`

Comment: It does not work? You mean like an error is thrown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("input[name='rdoInput'][value='Yes']").attr("checked", true);
```

or

```
$("input[name='rdoInput']:eq(0)").attr("checked", true);
```

---

**A Better Way:**

```
var value = sg.d.Input ? "Yes" : "No";

// set the value
$("input[name='rdoInput'][value='" + value + "']").attr("checked", true);

// get the value
var checkedValue = $("input[name='rdoInput']:checked").val();
```

---

working example: http://jsfiddle.net/xVDxZ/1/

Comment: +1, was going to specify the [value=] myself 'til the orange bar beat me to it. ;p

Answer (score 1):

Use eq(n):

```
 $('input[name="rdoInput"]').eq(0).attr('checked', true);
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the value of the currently checked radio button in the group, use this:

```
$('input:radio[name="rdoInput"]:checked').val()
```